# Suppose all the zeros of $f(x)$ are constructible. Show that $f(x)$ is solvable by radicals.

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field, solvable-groups

I know that a root $\alpha$ is constructible if [$Q(\alpha):Q$] = $2^n$ for some integer *n*. If $\Sigma$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$, $n \leq [\Sigma : Q] =Gal(f(x)) \leq n!$ so, in this case, $2^n \leq [\Sigma : Q] = Gal(f(x)) \leq 2^n!$

I want to somehow use this to show that $Gal(f(x))$ is solvable, but I'm unsure of where to go from here. Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think "solvable by radicals" just means that the zeroes of $f$ have radical expressions, so the question is really asking whether every constructible number has a radical expression, which is true because every step in a geometric construction gives you (more or less) the square root of a previously constructible number.

Comment: Unless you need to work from a more precise definition of solvability by radicals, of course...